# How can I implement project based matrix security in jenkins using script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-job-dsl

I need to implement the project based security in jenkins using cli or dsl.
http://www.tothenew.com/blog/jenkins-implementing-project-based-matrix-authorization-strategy/

How can I do that?

Comment: did you get anywhere with this? I know the puppet-jenkins project were looking at this but it sounds like you lose the cli as soon as you set matrix permissions.

Comment: nope. I did not get anywhere with this.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I will go down the config.xml route instead then.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old but just in case someone else runs across it...

For implementing it in a job DSL you can use this:

```
freeStyleJob('test_job_for_project_auth') {
    authorization {
        permission('hudson.model.Item.Discover', 'anonymous')
        permissions('myUserOrGroup', [
                'hudson.model.Item.Build',
                'hudson.model.Item.Discover',
                'hudson.model.Item.Cancel'
        ])
    }
  ...
}
```

Here is the doc url: 
https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.IvyJob.authorization